# How do I use a pipe to redirect the output of one command to the input of another?

Tags: windows, pipe, command-prompt

I have a program which sends text to an LED sign.

prismcom.exe

To use the program to send "Hello":

```
prismcom.exe usb Hello
```

Now, I wish to, for example use a command program called Temperature.

```
temperature
```

Let's say the program gives your computer's temperature.

```
Your computer is 100 degrees Fahrenheit.
```

Now, I wish to write the output of temperature to prismcom.exe:

```
temperature | prismcom.exe usb
```

This does not seem to work.

Yes, I've looked for a solution to this for more than twenty minutes. In all cases, they are either kludges/hacks or a solution for something besides the Windows command line.

I would appreciate direction as to how I would pipe the output from temperature to prismcom.

Thanks!

Edit: Prismcom has two arguments. The first will always be 'usb'. Anything that comes after that will be displayed on the sign.

Comment: If "temperature" is made to write to standard output and "prismcom" is made to read from standard input and write to standard output then this should Just Work. If not, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: prismcom has two arguments: usb;  and then whatever comes after is sent to the sign.

Comment: Could it be that temperature sends it's output to stderr rather than stdout?  Try `temperature 2>&1 | prismcom usb`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this. Copy this into a batch file - such as send.bat - and then simply run `send.bat` to send the message from the temperature program to the prismcom program.

```
temperature.exe > msg.txt
set /p msg= < msg.txt
prismcom.exe usb "%msg%"
```

Answer (score 19):

This should work:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %i in ('temperature') do prismcom.exe usb %i
```

If running in a batch file, you need to use `%%i` instead of just `%i` (in both places).

Answer (score 17):

You can also run exactly same command at Cmd.exe command-line using PowerShell. I'd go with this approach for simplicity...

```
C:\>PowerShell -Command "temperature | prismcom.exe usb"
```

Please read up on [Understanding the Windows PowerShell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines)

You can also type in `C:\>PowerShell` at the command-line and it'll put you in `PS C:\>` mode instanctly, where you can directly start writing PS.

Comment: That would pipe the standard output of `temperature` into the standard input of `prismcom`, wouldn't it?  That's not what the question asks for; the output of `temperature` has to become one of the command-line arguments of `prismcom`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston In that case, in order for it to work, prismcom must implement the function of treating stdin the same way it treats the argument, musn't it?

Answer (score -5):

Not sure if you are coding these programs, but this is a simple example of how you'd do it.

program1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char * argv[] ) {
    printf("%s", argv[1]); 
    return 0;
}
```

rgx.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char * argv[] ) {
    char input[200];
    fgets(input,200,stdin);
    string s(input)
    smatch m;
    string reg_exp(argv[1]);
    regex e(reg_exp);
    while (regex_search (s,m,e)) {
      for (auto x:m) cout << x << " ";
      cout << endl;
      s = m.suffix().str();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile both then run `program1.exe "this subject has a submarine as a subsequence" | rgx.exe "\b(sub)([^ ]*)"`

The `|` operator simply redirects the output of program1's `printf` operation from the `stdout` stream to the `stdin` stream whereby it's sitting there waiting for rgx.exe to pick up.