# How to pipe "echoed" statements to be read by a second function TWICE?

Tags: pipe, echo

Suppose I have a script READER that goes:

```
#! /bin/ksh
read line1
echo "$line1 read!"
read line2
echo "$line2 read!"
```

I could do something from the command line like...

`echo "schwifty" | READER`

...which would successfully output "schwifty read!" but what if I want to input something for line1 AND line2?

if I could `echo schwifty` then `echo schwifty2` from the same line and receive the following output:

```
schwifty read!
schwifty2 read!
```

...that would be perfect. IS there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Echo your output to a file and then just use that as input to the program. So something like

echo "Hi There" > out.dat | p1 < out.dat | p2 < out.dat

The above may not work though.  But your best bet is to go look up command line commands. Such as from:

[How do I use a pipe to redirect the output of one command to the input of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574170/how-do-i-use-a-pipe-to-redirect-the-output-of-one-command-to-the-input-of-anothe)

and

https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true