# Running Query from text file

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a big query query from the command line, but because my query is very long I've written it in a text file. The query works from the GUI and I'm overwriting a table that already exsists

```
bq query --allow_large_results --replace --destination_table=me.Tbl_MyTable  '`cat query.txt`'
```

However, I'm getting error results:

> Error in query string: Error processing job
>   'dev:bqjob_r_00000123456789456123_1': Encountered " 
>   "\'`cat query.txt`\' "" at line 1, column 1.
>   Was expecting: EOF

- Do I need to put the entire file path in the .txt filename? (this doesn't seem to make a difference)
- Are there any characters I need to be careful with in the text file (e.g. "\" or quotation marks) ?
- I'm using where clauses and group by clauses - is that an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `cat`, just pipe the input from the file. The command would be:

```
bq query --allow_large_results --replace --destination_table=me.Tbl_MyTable < query.txt
```

This will send the contents of `query.txt` to the `bq` tool.

Answer (score 2):

Elliot is right, now if you want to cat, sed or anything, pipe it:

```
cat query.txt | bq query
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work for me, doesn't recognise cat as a function (??)

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: Solution would involve something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574170/how-do-i-use-a-pipe-to-redirect-the-output-of-one-command-to-the-input-of-anothe, but I don't have Win7 to test it...