# BigQuery Illegal Escape Sequence for backslash /

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using UDF to do a little regex for phrase like 'test/test' and I came across an error that I can't correct.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION parseMethod(queryString STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS
\"\"\"
var match_regex = /test\/(\w+)/i;
var found_method;
if(found_method = queryString.match(match_regex)){
  method_list = found_method[1];
}
return method_list;
\"\"\";

SELECT
parseMethod('test/test') AS result
```

When I run this code, I get an error saying

```
Error in query string: Error processing job
'click-1315:XXXXXXXX': Syntax error:
Illegal escape sequence: \/
```

The javascript function works fine in node.js so I am guessing parsing of BigQuery doesn't like this format. I also tried `\\/` but same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove the backslashes in the `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION` statement and add a couple in the regex. This seems to work:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION parseMethod(queryString STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS
"""
var match_regex = /test\\/(\\w+)/i;
var found_method;
if(found_method = queryString.match(match_regex)){
  method_list = found_method[1];
}
return method_list;
""";

SELECT
parseMethod('test/test') AS result;
```

Comment: I had those `\"\"\"` because I was using the CLI in a shell script. Are you just using the bigquery api in some language?

Comment: I tried it through the UI. You can put that query text in a file, though, and then pipe it into the CLI. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41571272/6253347 for an example.