# Pipe text to stdin of running python process

Tags: python, stdin

Let's say I have a python script called service.py running as a kind of daemon in the background, and I want to give it some information by piping text into its stdin:

```
> pgrep -f service.py
[pid of process]
> echo -e 'test\n' > /proc/[pid of process]/fd/0
```

My python script should take whatever is in its stdin and **assign it** to a variable *inp*:

```
import sys
while True: 
   inp = sys.stdin.readline()
   #do something with inp
```

But when i do the above, it just prints the stdin stream:

```
> python service.py 
test
```

The effect is the same if I literally just have this in my script

```
import sys
inp = sys.stdin.readline() #sys.stdin.readline() never returns
                           #script never exits
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code to see if `inp` actually gets assigned to some value? Problem could be in the code of the `while` loop somewhere else.

Comment: No, sys.stdin.readline() never returns, everything I put after never gets executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write data to existing process's STDIN from external process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process)

Comment: @languitar you're right, it is, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you can use *named pipe* with `mkfifo` (https://serverfault.com/questions/443297/write-to-stdin-of-a-running-process-using-pipe)

> That leaves you with:
>
> ```
> mkfifo yourfifo
> cat > yourfifo &
> mypid=$!
> yourprogram < yourfifo
> ```
>
> Now you can sent data to your program with
>
> ```
> `echo "Hello World" > yourfifo`
> ```

(https://askubuntu.com/questions/449132/why-use-a-named-pipe-instead-of-a-file)

the key is that stdin has to be known as  *pipe* or *named pipe* this is why you can use `mkfifo`, see also [How to write data to existing process's STDIN from external process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process) (python part) and  [How to write data to existing process's STDIN from external process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process) (os part)

Comment: What about on Windows?

Comment: On Windows i do not know exactly, however it appears that it is more complex and limited.  On windows (Named) pipes are only supported within an app container **Windows 10, version 1709:** *Pipes are only supported within an app-container; ie, from one UWP process to another UWP process that's part of the same app. Also, named pipes must use the syntax ".\pipe\LOCAL" for the pipe name.*
source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getnamedpipeclientprocessid

Comment: also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780(v=vs.85).aspx and  **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574170/how-do-i-use-a-pipe-to-redirect-the-output-of-one-command-to-the-input-of-anothe**