# Passing additional "arguments" to a telnet connection command

Tags: windows, cmd, telnet, piping

I have a server that takes whatever data is sent to it and sends it back. With netcat on linux I am able to exectue the `nc ip port` command with an additional "argument" in a single line:

```
python -c print("Hello!") | nc ip port
```

This is equivalent to first running `nc ip port` to connect to the server, and later typing `Hello!` in the opened prompt to send the data.

While I know how to pass an output from a script to another script in windows (ex. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574170/how-do-i-use-a-pipe-to-redirect-the-output-of-one-command-to-the-input-of-anothe)), I am fairly unsure how to achieve a similar result using telnet, as `telnet ip port` opens its own prompt (which means disabling windows commands).

I would like to know if it is at all possible with telnet to achieve what piping in linux does, or if there is a similar, minimalistic software that I could use on windows.

Comment: Answered on [su] - [https://superuser.com/questions/14501/are-there-netcat-like-tools-for-windows-which-are-not-quarantined-as-malware](https://superuser.com/questions/14501/are-there-netcat-like-tools-for-windows-which-are-not-quarantined-as-malware)

Comment: @DavidPostill That's great, I will look especially into MobaXterm (netcat for windows also opens another prompt and therefore has similar issues as telnet)